# Relationship between speed against armature current/torque in DC shunt motor

Tags: motor, dc, shunt

I do not understand why the graph is like this as below when we use flux control method of DC shunt motor

Also, can I change the x-axis of this graph to be armature current instead since equation of motor speed is given by:[image]

and I take y-intercept to be V/kphi, and gradient to be -Ra/kphi

However, if I do that the graph does not make sense, because the slope of gradient should increase when flux decreases from increasing resistance

[image]

Comment: "*slope of gradient*" : What does this phrase mean ?

Comment: my bad, jus gradient

Comment: The z axis is torque. The equation you have shown has only current in it; not torque. Does the current to torque relation also contain in it, a term with \$\phi\$ ?